# requesting a form via $.ajax returns only form elements

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I'm using AJAX to fetch a form dynamically into another page for security reasons. The Ajax works fine but the result is displaying form elements only not the form tag

```
$.ajax('form.php?username='+username).done(function (data) {
     alert(data);
     $("#test").html(data);
})
```

The alert displays the whole form including the form tag with the related attributes but the form does not submit because the form tag has been removed and while checking the code through firebug that's what I found

[image]

and this the result of alert(data)

[image]

I've tried this but it didn't insert the form tag at all

```
$("#test").html(data).promise().done(function(){
    $("#test").html.wrap('<form action="page.php">');
});
```

Comment: Note: `html(data)` returns the jQuery element, then `promise()` returns an *animation queue promise*, so unless you animated the element it will never fire.

Comment: the page already contains the complete form markup but the request returns elements only not the form tag

Comment: Is `#test` child of another FORM? If ya, then it is invalid and browser engine strips out nested FORM tags. Anyway, you would have better to explain what you are looking for, `I'm using AJAX to fetch a form dynamically into another page for security reasons` ***this*** sounds like a XY problem

Comment: @ A. Wolff Thanks a lot I totally forgot it. my mistake you can add your comment so I can accept it as an answer

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A FORM cannot contains any other FORM, see [Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#prohibitions)

> form must not contain other form elements.

Browser engine strips out any nested FORM tags.